# PHP MySQL Email table with lines when the table data has html code

Tags: php, mysql

I created this project when I started learning code and instead of writing each part number to its own row, each part number is in the same column with a line break after each part number. When the data is echoed on an email, there's no line divider between each row and its hard to read the table.

I was going to recreate the project and when a parts request is submitted on the form, and save each part number to its own row but i was curious to see if there are any bright ideas on a workaround.

Here's what the table looks like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      partnumber     |    partdescrip   |
|---------------------|------------------|
| part1<br>part2      | desc1<br>desc2   |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And here's the form

```
if (isset($_POST['saveandsubmitbutton'])) {

  $partnumber = $_POST['partnumber'];
  $partdescrip = $_POST['partdescrip'];

   echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $partnumber . '</td>
            <td>' . $partdescrip . '</td>
         </tr>';
```

and here is the output:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      partnumber     |    partdescrip   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|      part1          |        desc1     |
|      part2          |        desc2     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The results i'm looking for is:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      partnumber     |    partdescrip   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       part1         |      desc1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|       part2         |      desc2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: show us your whole table creation code

Comment: `save each part number to its own row` is the proper solution to this.

Comment: I might recommend using CSS to hide the borders on the top and bottom of those cells. It will keep everything neatly aligned, work well with the loop you have in place, and give you the desired appearance. Keep the borders on the `<th>` header row and it can look exactly how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Saving each part to its own row would definitely be best practice, and I would aim to do that in future. But a workaround for now could be:

```
   if (isset($_POST['saveandsubmitbutton'])) {
        $partnumber = $_POST['partnumber'];
        $partdescrip = $_POST['partdescrip'];
        $partDesc = explode("<br>", $_POST['partdescrip']);
        foreach ($partDesc as $desc) {
            echo '<tr>
            <td>' . $partnumber . '</td>
            <td>' . $desc . '</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }
```